# Keyboard Layout Failure (Symbols & Signs) - Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I have found a **HUGE** "Bug" or "Feature" that really screwed everything up!

I accidentally pressed the wrong key at the bottom left that i suspect is a bad shortcut and now i can't use the keyboard at all.

For some unknown reason it started to write **Symbols & Signs** only where it is supposed to write my main language normally with letters only.

I could write in other languages but not in my native language.

**How i tried to fix this issue:**

**1)** Restarted PC, it then started up in (Safe Mode) but i couldn't press any key like, Enter, Up/Down key to pick an option. I waited for the counter to run out of time and it then started up in default mode. Was **not** able to enter my password, the screen just kept flickering between Blackscreen and back to the password window when i tried to enter the password.

**2)** Since the restart didn't help i completely shut Down PC/Unplugged Keyboard and Cut The Power. Then restarted the PC again and then I was able to enter the decryption password (Even Though The Screen kept Flickering back and forth In Blackscreen every time I pressed a new letter) But when trying to enter the account password it failed again.

**3)** Shut down the PC again and plugged in another Keyboard (The one I'm writing from now) and it worked like a sharm. So after i managed to log back in again i tried to replug back to my default Keyboard but the problem was still there.

The normal **Power Off** button in top right corner was also gone, the Power Button was changed to an " Paus symbol and when i clicked on it it just logged me out and ofcourse I couldn't log back in again after that so had to change back to my old reserve Keyboard again.

I really need help to fix this i have no idea what to do. I want my old keyboard back in normal again :(

Thank's in advance!

Comment: With the keyboard that works, have you tried looking at what keyboard you have selected and any shortcuts set?

Comment: Graham@ I have never set any shortcuts myself, almost everything is in default settings. I've been using both these keyboards for years (This is the first time I use this Keyboard in this OS) I only changed because I had no other options. If knew what key I pressed i would happily have told that in my main post. However I do not dare try finding that key again, then i wont have a keyboard at all since I don't know how to fix it back to normal again. :(

Comment: Graham@ I really appreciate that you tried to help me! I have now solved the problem (Se post below) Have a wonderful Sunday :)

Answer (score 0):

**[SOLVED]**

I didn't notice it until someone mentioned it in another post! This was an embarrassing fix!

On your keyboard right side to the Spacebar button there is a button named: **[Alt Gr]**
That key had got stuck so I just had to loosen it, after i did that everything went back to normal again. :)